# Ui Router not showing nested child content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my current code:

```
let views = { '': 'app/content.html' };

.state('auto', {
    url: '/automated',
    redirectToChild: {
        state: 'auto.index'
    },
    views: view
})
.state('auto.index', {
    url :'',
    templateUrl: '/app/automated/automated.html'
})
.state('auto.visit', {
    url: '/visit',
    views: {
        '': {templateUrl: '/app/automated/visit.html'}
     }
})
.state('auto.visit.create', {
    url: '/create',
    views: {
        '': {templateUrl: '/app/automated/_form.html'}
    }
})
```

Here is my html:

```
// index.html
<ui-view></ui-view>


// content.html

 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <ui-view> </ui-view>
    </div>
</div>


// visit.html
<h5>Visit Page</h5>

// form.html
<h5>Visit Form</h5>
```

Here is the problem: Everything works fine with this code but when I visit `auto.visit.create` state it show `visit.html` instead of '_form.html'.

How can I replace `visit.html` content without changing current routes?

---

First Tried:
I change my `auto.visit.create` state to `auto.visit-create`. This way is working perfectly but I want `create` is child of `auto.visit`

Second Tried:
I put new `<ui-view></ui-view>` on visit.html but when I go to `create` page it will show visit.html content.

I've tried to follow this http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/ code. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

How are you visiting the nested views?  The notation you want works perfectly.
you should include the `<ui-view></ui-view>`in all parent pages.

See the plunker I created as an example; be sure to open the preview in using the separate page view so that you can see the urls that are being generated

---

### UPDATE

I misunderstood your question, I apologize.  Below is the updated code and plunker that achieves what you desire.  I don't believe there is any way to accomplish this purely through angular routing so I used jquery to do it. only changes are on **first layer** and **second layer**

http://plnkr.co/edit/cxQpu6zS7fifnb0sGvGf?p=preview

Angular Code

```
(function() {
  angular.module("myApp", ["ui.router"]);

  angular.module("myApp")
    .config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function($stateProvider,        $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  $stateProvider
    .state("home", {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "blank.html"
    })
    .state("first", {
      url: "/first",
      templateUrl: "firstLayerPage.html"
    })
    .state("first.second", {
      url: "/second",
      templateUrl: "secondLayerPage.html"
    })
    .state("first.second.third1", {
      url: "/third_Page1",
      templateUrl: "thirdLayerPage1.html"
    })
    .state("first.second.third2", {
      url: "/third_Page2",
      templateUrl: "thirdLayerPage2.html"
    })
}]); // end of config
})(); //end of enclosure
```

Index

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="home">home</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="first">First Layer</a> </li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Home Page</h1>
  <hr>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

first layer

```
  <p>this is the first layer of pages.</p>
  <ul>
      <li><a id="showSecondLayer" ui-sref="first.second">Second Layer</a>     </li>
  </ul>
   <hr>
   <ui-view></ui-view>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#showSecondLayer").click(function(){
         $("#secondLayer").show();
       });
     });
   </script>
```

second layer

```
<div id="secondLayer">
  <p>This is the second layer</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="thirdP1" ui-sref="first.second.third1">Third Layer Page 1</a> </li>
    <li><a id="thirdP2" ui-sref="first.second.third2">Third Layer Page 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
</div>
<ui-view></ui-view>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#thirdP1").click(function(){
      $("#secondLayer").hide();
    });
    $("#thirdP2").click(function(){
      $("#secondLayer").hide();
    });
  });      
</script>
```

third layer p1

```
<p>This is page one of the third level of children</p>
<hr>
```

third layer p2

```
<p>This is page two of the third level of children</p>
<hr>
```

Comment: Ok ill check my code. I use ui-sred to visit my nested views

Comment: I've see your example. Is there any way using your router setup but, when I click on third layer p1 it will replace second layer instead (problem that i having right now).

Comment: I am able to accomplish what you are looking for using jquery.  I updated my answer and plunker to reflect that behavior

Comment: It might be helpful to update your title as it's a little confusing with what you are actually asking