# How to do url routing in angular js with $urlRouterProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing, angular-routing

Can anybody provide a simple angular js page which implements the ui-view and url Routing using  $urlRouterProvider attribute

Regards,

Seshi

Comment: Before asking a question you should add your code parts or snippets about what have you been tried for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160083/ui-router-not-showing-nested-child-content/37171404#37171404

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole lot of documentation and examples on UI-Router homepage.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

There is a sample app
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/